# Pyspark - sum rows of table with same ID

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to combine 2 tables in such a way that rows with the same ID (the ID may be a combination of multiple columns) are summed together. Rows without a match of either table are still retained.

Here is an illustration of what I had in mind. `C1` & `C2` are the ID columns whilst `W1` and `W2` are the rows to be summed.

DF A:

| C1 | C2 | W1 | W2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | 5 | 3 |
| A | B | 6 | 7 |
| B | A | 2 | 3 |
| B | B | 8 | 8 |

[DFA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9YWH.png)

DF B:

| C1 | C2 | W1 | W2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | 2 | 7 |
| A | C | 4 | 8 |
| B | A | 9 | 1 |
| B | D | 3 | 5 |

[DFB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRLnJ.png)

Resulting dataframe

| C1 | C2 | W1 | W2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | 7 | 10 |
| A | B | 6 | 7 |
| A | C | 4 | 8 |
| B | A | 11 | 4 |
| B | B | 8 | 8 |
| B | D | 3 | 5 |

[Resulting DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aQZF.png)

I had two ideas, but I can't get either implemented at the moment. The first is to do a union on both dataframes and then do a groupby aggregation but I am unsure if this is the most efficient approach.

The other was doing an outer join on both Data frames and then summing the common columns. I had trouble implementing this as the ID columns come from a list and are variables that change from time to time and so the join can't be hard coded.

Answer (score 0):

the `full_join` would be easy to implement even if you have list of columns that can change over time.

here's an example using your samples

```py
id_cols = ['c1', 'c2']
sum_cols = ['w1', 'w2']

data1_sdf.alias('a'). \
    join(data2_sdf.alias('b'), id_cols, 'full'). \
    selectExpr(*id_cols,
               *['(coalesce(a.{0}, 0) + coalesce(b.{0}, 0)) as {0}'.format(c) for c in sum_cols]
               ). \
    show()

# +---+---+---+---+
# | c1| c2| w1| w2|
# +---+---+---+---+
# |  A|  A|  7| 10|
# |  A|  C|  4|  8|
# |  B|  B|  8|  8|
# |  B|  A| 11|  4|
# |  B|  D|  3|  5|
# |  A|  B|  6|  7|
# +---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the two dataframes as "full" and sum the columns where not null:

```py
dfa = spark.createDataFrame(data=[["A","A","5","3"],["A","B","6","7"],["B","A","2","3"],["B","B","8","8"]], schema=["C1","C2","W1","W2"])

dfb = spark.createDataFrame(data=[["A","A","2","7"],["A","C","4","8"],["B","A","9","1"],["B","D","3","5"]], schema=["C1","C2","W1","W2"])

result_df = dfa \
  .join(dfb, (dfa.C1 == dfb.C1) & (dfa.C2 == dfb.C2), how="full") \
  .withColumn("C1_new", F.coalesce(dfa.C1, dfb.C1)) \
  .withColumn("C2_new", F.coalesce(dfa.C2, dfb.C2)) \
  .withColumn("W1_sum", F.when(dfa.W1.isNull(), dfb.W1).when(dfb.W1.isNull(), dfa.W1).otherwise((dfa.W1 + dfb.W1).cast('int'))) \
  .withColumn("W2_sum", F.when(dfa.W2.isNull(), dfb.W2).when(dfb.W2.isNull(), dfa.W2).otherwise((dfa.W2 + dfb.W2).cast('int'))) \
  .drop("C1", "C2", "W1", "W2")

[Out]:
+------+------+------+------+
|C1_new|C2_new|W1_sum|W2_sum|
+------+------+------+------+
|     A|     A|     7|    10|
|     A|     B|     6|     7|
|     A|     C|     4|     8|
|     B|     A|    11|     4|
|     B|     B|     8|     8|
|     B|     D|     3|     5|
+------+------+------+------+
```